# Fragment replace doesnt work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-radiogroup

I'm having a radio group that changes my fragments in the activity when a the selected radiobutton is changed. I have this code:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.main_menu1:
                showOffersFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.main_menu2:
                openMap();
                break;
            case R.id.main_menu3:
                showProductsFragment();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showProductsFragment() {
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        if (productsFragment == null) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(ActivityConstants.PRODUCT_ITEMS, products);
            productsFragment = new ProductFragment();
            productsFragment.setArguments(bundle); ft.add(R.id.main_frag_container, productsFragment, "products");

        } else {
            //TODO
            ft.replace(R.id.main_frag_container, productsFragment, "products");
            productsFragment.loadList(products);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }
private void showOffersFragment() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OFFERS NULL OR :" + (offersFragment == null)+" ITEMS ="+items.size());

        fm = getFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (offersFragment == null) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(ActivityConstants.OFFER_ITEMS, items);
            offersFragment = new OffersFragment();
            offersFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.add(R.id.main_frag_container, offersFragment,"offers");
        } else {
            ft.replace(R.id.main_frag_container, offersFragment,"offers");
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
  private void openMap() {
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        if(mapFragment==null){
            mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.main_frag_container, mapFragment, "Map");
        }else{
            ft.replace(R.id.main_frag_container, mapFragment, "Map");
        }
        ft.commit();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

Now the problem is when I switch between fragments. Its not changing the fagments right away so its not responding very well. I should switch between them couple of times so the fragment can appear.

Can anyone tell me how can I optimize/make it work propperly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not respond right away, because at a start, once you choose each option, this line is run `ft.add(R.id.main_frag_container, mapFragment, "Map");`, which means you are adding new fragment into the same container instead of replacing an old one.

Use `ft.replace(R.id.main_frag_container, mapFragment, "Map");` instead of `ft.add(R.id.main_frag_container, mapFragment, "Map");`. Though I might be wrong, but container (here R.id.main_fragment_container) has to have fragment already added, one option would be to add fragment only if container is empty, replace otherwise.

You might want to check [addToBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) if you wish to navigate back through previous fragments.